# python pandas tabloo viewer. How to return to interactive prompt?

Tags: python, pandas, viewer

I just installed the tabloo dataFrame viewer.
When entering the command
tabloo.show(df)
the dataframe is shown in a Firefox window.
Closing Firefox does not return the python prompt:

```
>>> tabloo.show(D2)
 * Serving Flask app 'tabloo.server'
 * Debug mode: off
^C>>>type here
```

I think `<Ctrl-C>` is *not* the way to return to the python prompt.
What is?
Thanks, Gerrit

I think I understand that python will only return the prompt after closing the interactive window.
Closing the window on Firefox did not return the prompt.
I looked on the page to find a close button, but failed.

So is there an alternative to `<ctrl-C>`?

Comment: Consider choosing [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) to attract the right helpers. Reserve [python-3.x] for versioning issues, otherwise fall back to [python].

Comment: what is tabloo dataFrame viewer?

Comment: It is the viewer I got from here:
https://github.com/bluenote10/tabloo

Comment: Looks like maybe something to ask tabloo's author directly, @bluenote10. Have you noticed he is around on SO?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am still learning, both python and stack-overflow.